# How to write multiple lines of text in math mode and keep them centered?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I can't seem to figure out how to achieve the following. I've tried using

```
\left.\begin{cases} 


\textrm{morphisms from V to W} \\\\

\textrm{k-algebra blablabla}

\end{cases}\right\}
```

But the text isn't centered like in the picture. Thanks for the help! [image]

Answer (score 1):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{array}

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{\hskip2pt}c@{\hskip2pt}}
\text{morphisms from } V \text{ to } W\\
k-\text{algebra blablabla}
\end{array}
\right\}
\longleftrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{\hskip2pt}c@{\hskip2pt}}
\text{morphisms from } V \text{ to } W\\
k-\text{algebra blablabla}
\end{array}
\right\}
\end{equation}

\section{tabular}

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{\hskip2pt}c@{\hskip2pt}}
morphisms from $V$ to $W$\\
$k$-algebra blablabla
\end{tabular}
\right\}
\longleftrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{\hskip2pt}c@{\hskip2pt}}
morphisms from $V$ to $W$\\
$k$-algebra blablabla
\end{tabular}
\right\}
\end{equation}

\section{tabularray}

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{tblr}{colspec={c},colsep={2pt}}
\text{morphisms from } V \text{ to } W\\
k-\text{algebra blablabla}
\end{tblr}
\right\}
\longleftrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{tblr}{colspec={c},colsep={2pt}}
\text{morphisms from } V \text{ to } W\\
k-\text{algebra blablabla}
\end{tblr}
\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can simply use `tabular`, no package needed.

Comment: @Sigur Thank you. I am used to using tabularray.

Comment: You don't need `\text{}` in `tabular` since the cell contents is already in text mode. You need `$V$` instead.

Comment: @Sigur Thank you for reminding me, I have corrected my answer.

Comment: Welcome. Observe that `k` should be in math mode and the rest, in text mode, that is, `-algebra` includes the dash, otherwise it would be a minus sign.

Comment: @Sigur It doesn't matter. The core problem of OP is that it doesn't know how to use the table. Others will be modified by themselves.

Comment: Yes, I know. But it is good to keep correct code for others who only come and copy the code.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer I came up with (while Clara was posting) is similar to Clara's, but with regular tabular's and `@{}`'s to eliminate extra padding on the sides of the tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\[
\left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
morphisms~from~$V$~to~$W$\\
as~algebraic~sets
\end{tabular}
\right\}
\longleftrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
$k$-algebra homomorphisms\\
from $k[W]$ to $k[V]$
\end{tabular}
\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular in equation]

Comment: Is the word spelled "homomorphism" or "homeomorphism"? :-)

Comment: @Mico Definitely “homomorphism”, the other word denoting quite a different concept of topology.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks! (As you well know, I'm not a mathematician...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I really appreciate it